# Bluez5.7 Headset paired but not connecting HSP/HFP

Tags: bluetooth, kernel, bluez, headset, hfp

I need your help in solving Bluez5.7 headset connect issue.

Goal is to implement Wideband speech with a WBS compatible headset.
To support Wideband speech, I understand HFP1.6 should be integrated. To support HFP 1.6 Profile, we have integrated Bluez 5.7 (or 5.5.7) and Ofono 1.16, dBus v 1.4.16.

The host Processor is interfaced to BT chip using UART (for signaling) and TDM (for audio data in I2S/PCM Interface)

I’m able to power on the hci interface as following:
•   bccmd -t bcsp -d /dev/ttyS1 -b 115200 psload -r /etc/bluetooth/platform_8810.psr (Firmware Download)
•   hciattach -s 115200 ttyS1 bcsp 115200 noflow
•   hciconfig hci0 noauth
•   hciconfig hci0 up
•   hciconfig hci0 noauth

Scan is also successful using: “hcitool scan”

Pairing is also successful using: “hcitool cc  && hcitool auth ”

For connect, Im using test-device script provided in Bluez5-7 /usr/lib/bluez/test/

Following are the UUIDs supported by the Headset we are using (I saw this using bluetoothctl tool)

[bluetooth]# info 48:C1:AC:29:7F:27
Device 48:C1:AC:29:7F:27
        Class: 0x240404
        Icon: audio-card
        Paired: yes
        Trusted: yes
        Blocked: no
        Connected: no
        LegacyPairing: no
        UUID: Headset                   (00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Handsfree                 (0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        Modalias: bluetooth:v0055p001Bd0610

if I give: 
./test-device connect 48:C1:AC:29:7F:27 "hsp"

In BluezDaemon context, it goes to

bluetoothd[523]: src/device.c:connect_profiles()

bluetoothd[523]: src/device.c:connect_profiles() /org/bluez/hci0/dev_48_C1_AC_29_7F_27 00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, client :1.6

Then it goes to  src/device.c:find_connectable_service()

Its looping thru the registered services in this function. (I have put prints and saw this)

There are 2 services registered with Bluez, ie,
audio-sink(0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb) and 
A/V Remote Control (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb).

In this services list, HFP or HSP is not present, so it is returning without executing any Connect function.

And in the console where Im executing the test-script, Im getting the following error:

```
  /usr/lib/bluez/test# ./test-device connect 48:C1:AC:29:7F:27 "hsp"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test-device", line 102, in <module>
    device.ConnectProfile(args[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 70, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in __call__
    **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.bluez.Error.InvalidArguments: Invalid arguments in method call
```

Please help !

Comment: as i remember that hfp support is moved from bluez to ofono, is there any tool available in ofono to initiate connection via bluez?

Answer (score 0):

Export the `DBUS_SYSTEM_BUS_ADDRESS` path, where you are executing test-device script.

```
export DBUS_SYSTEM_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/usr/local/bluez/dbus-1.8.6/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
```